# pandas read_json in chunks but still has memory error

Tags: pandas, large-files

I'm trying to read and process a large json file(~16G) but it keeps having memory error even if I read in small chunks by specifying chunksize=500. My code:

```
i=0
header = True
for chunk in pd.read_json('filename.json.tsv', lines=True, chunksize=500):
        print("Processing chunk ", i)
        process_chunk(chunk, i)
        i+=1
        header = False
```

```
def process_chunk(chunk, header, i):
    pk_file = 'data/pk_files/500_chunk_'+str(i)+'.pk'
    get_data_pk(chunk, pk_file) #load and process some columns and save into a pk file for future processing
    preds = get_preds(pk_file) #SVM prediction
    chunk['prediction'] = preds #append result column
    chunk.to_csv('result.csv', header = header, mode='a')
```

The process_chunk function basically reads in each chunk and append a new column to it.

When I use a smaller file it works, also works well if I specify nrows=5000 in the read_json function. Seems for some reason it still requires full file-size memory despite the chunksize parameter.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Does `process_chunk` also attempt to append all of the data you've processed?

Comment: can you also post the code for `process_chunk` and the full error message?

Comment: I paid attention to this and tried to only use in-chunk data in each chunk, but the error seems like it still requires whole data at some time.

Comment: were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: Hey, yes downgrading pandas to v1.0.5 works for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same strange problem in one of my project's virtual env with pandas v1.1.2.
Downgrading pandas to v1.0.5 seems to solve the problem.

Comment: It turned out that it's probably a bug introduced by the new feature "nrows" introduced to limit  total number of rows loaded: if you add the parameter "nrows=<N>", with N grater than the total number of rows in the file - in this case - the chunksize limit works again.

Comment: @Olmo Thank you for the `nrows` trick, not sure why it works but it does! I had the same issue with the v1.1.2. Upgrading to v1.1.4 also solved the issue.

Comment: I'm observing this issue in v1.1.5. Setting `nrows` helps, thanks!